# Eclipse associates .js files with .sql editor

Tags: eclipse

All of a sudden, Eclipse Kepler (build id 20140224-0627) is associating all my .js files with the .sql editor.

Preferences/General/Content Types -> JS Script shows File Association:

> *.js (locked)

Preferences/General/Editors/File Associations -> *.js shows a sql icon, and Associated Editors also shows a sql icon, followed by

> JS Worksheet (default) (locked by 'JS Script' content type)

All .js files that were previously opened look fine in their editors. However, when using the Project Explorer to open other .js files, they all show a sql icon, and when opened, almost every line has an error next to it, and the top of the editor tab shows

> Connection: (not connected)

followed by the regular SQL editor icons.

Could this be a corrupted workspace? No error was given.

Google gives me nothing. I've restarted Eclipse and my VM. I've also tried opening in clean mode.

I've also tried adding a new file association (for madeup file type *.foo) and when adding an associated editor, the JS Script editor has a sql icon.

UPDATE:

I'm wondering whether something happened when I had to update my Toad Extension because it expired. I ran into problems while doing so but had gotten it to update eventually. However, now I see that I have two separate entries for "Toad Extension" under Preferences.Looking at Installed Software, I see duplicate entries for the Core Plugin and the Oracle Database Plugin, from Quest and from Dell. I'm not sure which I should un-install... perhaps I should un-install all and then re-install again? It looks like the Dell plugins are more recent. Hm..

UPDATE 2:
Tried un-installing all Toad Plugins, then re-installed just the Core Plugin and the Oracle Database Plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace. No change; also tried opening in clean mode.

Comment: Look at the Preferences in 'General > Content Types' and 'General > Editors > File Associations' for the JavaScript setttings. Also note that Eclipse remembers which editor was used last for a file and reuses that editor unless you tell to open using the default editor.

Comment: @greg-449, I've updated my post to add more detail.